# Example and usage for Func<Func<T>,T>

Tags: c#

I have been trying to come up with a case that using `Func<Func<T>,T>` would be useful.

coming up with examples for `Func<T,T>` is trivial e.g.

```
Func<int,int> square = n => n*n;
```

But I can't come up with sample case that uses something like `Func<Func<T>,T>`

on the other hand coming up for a usage for `Func<T,Func<T>>`

seems trivial e.g.

```
Func<int,Func<int,int>> k = k => square;
```

are there any well known uses cases for `Func<Func<T>,T>` or `Func<T,Func<T>>` or some refrence material that discusses similar topics?

Comment: let me rephrase my question... Why do you need to know if there is a usecase for such a construct?

Comment: Well, regarding your example, why not `Func<Func<int>, int> squaredSquare = n => n() * n();`? Think of something like "I want to do something to `x` but I want to defer the obtaining of `x` to someone else"

Comment: @Mischa Doesn't matter, it's a conceptual question.

Comment: @Arjang Even better, think of a retry function: `Func<Func<T>, T> retry = (func) => try { return func(); } catch { ...} return null;` (of course, add actual retry logic there)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto : a "retry function" is the first I hear the term, thank you.

Comment: @Arjang I might have just invented that term, so don't quote me on that :)

Comment: @Mischa : https://www.google.com.au/search?q=wir+m%C3%BCssen+wissen.+wir+werden+wissen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a good thing you didn't ask for a simple use case :)

**Use case:** Let's say you need to pool values from a device. Accessing the device is taxing (in some metric). Sometimes you are ok with getting old values (no real access to the device), sometimes you need the absolute latest values (must access the device) and sometimes you need something in between. Oh, and you also must be able to change the pooled values and/or device on the fly.

Here is how a solution to the above requirements might look like:

```
public class Cache
{
    public int? CachedValue { get; private set;}
    public DateTime cacheLastRetrieved { get; private set; }

    public void SetCache(int value)
    {
        CachedValue = value;
        cacheLastRetrieved = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Func<Func<int>, int> CacheStrategy;
    public void ResetCache()
    {
        CachedValue = null;
    }

    public int Get(Func<int> f)
    {
        return CacheStrategy(f);
    }
}
```

```
public static class CacheFactory
{
    private static Func<Func<int>, int>
    MakeCacheStrategy(Cache cache, Func<Cache, bool> mustGetRealValue)
    {
        return f =>
        {
            if (mustGetRealValue(cache))
            {
                int value = f();
                cache.SetCache(value);
                return value;               
            }               
            return (int)cache.CachedValue;
        };
    }

    public static Func<Func<int>, int> NoCacheStrategy(Cache cache)
    {
        return MakeCacheStrategy(cache, c => true);
    }

    public static Func<Func<int>, int> ForeverCacheStrategy(Cache cache)
    {
        return MakeCacheStrategy(cache, c => c.CachedValue == null);
    }

    public static Func<Func<int>, int>
    SimpleCacheStrategy(Cache cache, TimeSpan keepAliveTime)
    {
        return MakeCacheStrategy(cache,
            c => c.CachedValue == null
                 || c.cacheLastRetrieved + keepAliveTime < DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

```
public class Device
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();
    public int Get()
    {
        return rnd.Next(0, 100);
    }
}
```

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Device dev = new Device();
        Cache cache = new Cache();

        cache.ResetCache();
        cache.CacheStrategy = CacheFactory.NoCacheStrategy(cache);
        Console.Write("no cache strategy:            ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write(cache.Get(dev.Get) + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        cache.ResetCache();
        cache.CacheStrategy = CacheFactory.ForeverCacheStrategy(cache);
        Console.Write("forever cache strategy:       ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write(cache.Get(dev.Get) + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        cache.ResetCache();
        cache.CacheStrategy
            = CacheFactory.SimpleCacheStrategy(cache, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300));
        Console.Write("refresh after 300ms strategy: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write(cache.Get(dev.Get) + " ");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

> ```
> no cache strategy:            70 29 9 16 61 32 10 77 14 77 
> forever cache strategy:       96 96 96 96 96 96 96 96 96 96 
> refresh after 300ms strategy: 19 19 19 22 22 22 91 91 91 10
> ```

Comment: I didn't mean to put any restrictions, please ignore any constraints you think I have implied, I am happy with less or no restrictions too.